# Sort series per category

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/rtGFm/37/

I would like to have a "sort" button that sorts high to low each category, putting the columns in a different order for each category.  Is this possible with HighCharts?

```js
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'foreclosures',
                'nuisances',
                'distance from city center'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return ''+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Alger Heights',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 50]
        }, {
            name: 'Shawmut Hills',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 67]
        }, {
            name: 'Baxter',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 100]
        }, {
            name: 'Midtown',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 80]
        }, {
            type: 'scatter',
            data: [55,60,70],
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square',
                lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
                lineWidth: 1,
                radius: 8
            },
            name: 'Average'
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Would "No" be an acceptable answer?

Comment: If it is not possible, then yeah.

Comment: Well, I would say it is "No" from Highcharts API. However, you can create a js function that re-orders the objects in the series object. Then destroy/create the chart with newly ordered series array.

Comment: I don't think that would work either.  What is being requested is that the series order different within each group based on the sort.  I don't see a way to do that in one chart.  My suggestion would be to make this three bar charts in the form of small  multiples - [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple[/link]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem :) highcharts still does not provide any solution for this problem, but it is flexibel enough so that you can sort anyway - just by javascript.

Put your data in a separate value:

`var dataMain = [{name:"test1",data:5}, {name:"test1",data:1},{name:"test1",data:2}]`

In series you can just add a function which sorts your data:

`series: (function(){
    for(var i = 0;i<dataMain.length;i++){
        dataMain[i].data = dataMain[i].data.sort(function(a,b){
        return a[0] - b[0] ;
    })
    return dataMain;
}`

Hope I got everything wright.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't sort the category accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work, I believe. Trick is to add each column in correct order as a new serie with same type (column), reuse colors and hide legend...

Very hackish, the JS code to sort like 8 categories independently will be ugly but the result looks fine.

**Edit:** Updated fiddle, I see the spacing between the categories grows with series, doesn't look supernice.

My jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z2agkzt0/2/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
            inverted: true
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Series sorted in within categories'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['January']
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Stockholm',
            data: [{x:0, y:95, color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]}]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Göteborg',
            data: [{x:0, y:80, color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]}]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Göteborg',
            data: [{x: 1, name: 'February', y: 98, color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // VGR's color
            }],
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Stockholm',
            data: [{x: 1, name: 'February', y: 80, color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // VGR's color
            }],
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

br,
Jens

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done,

this may look like a little work around.

since we have a limited number of columns i mean 4 in the given example.

if we have arrays with sorting done with respect to each series then we can handle them.

on button click we can update the chart with new set of data as well as category array.

May be there is no solution from the APi.
According to me this is a possible approach.

Thanks,